# MultiLine Edit Text going behind other edit texts

Tags: android, xml, android-edittext

Basically when I hit enter to create a new line in the Edit Text, it creates another line but goes behind the other objects instead of pushing them down.
Here's the code I currently have:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/background"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
android:focusable="false"
android:paddingTop="5dp"
android:paddingRight="10dp"
android:paddingLeft="10dp"
android:paddingBottom="10dp"
android:id="@+id/rlRegister">




<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" >



    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="”
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text=""
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text=""
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"

            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"/>

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/etN"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/textView"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:hint=""
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:textColor="#303030"
            android:background="@drawable/textbox"/>

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/etD"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/textView2"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@id/etN"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:hint=""
            android:textColor="#303030"
            android:background="@drawable/textbox"/>


        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/etA"
            android:layout_below="@+id/etD"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_alignTop="@id/textView3"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@id/etD"
            android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
            android:hint=""
            android:textColor="#303030"
            android:background="@drawable/textbox"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text=""
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="200dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text=""
            android:id="@+id/textView5"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/etpNa"
            android:hint=""
            android:textColor="#303030"
            android:background="@drawable/textbox"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView5"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView5"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/etA"/>
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="140dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/etpNu"
            android:hint=" 
            android:textColor="#303030"
            android:background="@drawable/textbox"
            android:layout_below="@id/etpNa"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/etpNa"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>

        <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=""
            android:id="@+id/cb"
            android:layout_below="@+id/etpNu"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text=""
            android:id="@+id/tvI"
            android:layout_below="@+id/cb"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:visibility="invisible"/>
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/etiNa"
            android:hint=""
            android:textColor="#303030"
            android:background="@drawable/textbox"
            android:layout_below="@+id/cb"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tvI"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/etpNa"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/tvI"
            android:visibility="invisible"/>
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="140dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/etiNu"
            android:hint=" “
            android:textColor="#303030"
            android:background="@drawable/textbox"
            android:layout_below="@+id/etiNa"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/etiNa"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:visibility="invisible"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text=""
            android:id="@+id/textView6"
            android:layout_below="@+id/etiNu"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:singleLine="true"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text=""
            android:id="@+id/textView7"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView6"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView5"
            />

       <!--Affected Area below-->
        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:id="@+id/scrollView2"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView7"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView7"
            >
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/etMN"
            android:hint="”
            android:textColor="#303030"
            android:background="@drawable/textbox"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView7"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView6"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView7"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/etpNa"/>
        </ScrollView>

       <!--Affected Area End-->
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text=":"
            android:id="@+id/textView10"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView6"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/etpNu"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView6"
            android:layout_marginTop="70dp"/>
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/etECN"
            android:hint=""
            android:textColor="#303030"
            android:background="@drawable/textbox"
            android:layout_below="@id/scrollView2"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/textView10"
            android:layout_alignTop="@id/textView10"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@id/etpNa"/>
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/etECW"
            android:hint=""
            android:textColor="#303030"
            android:background="@drawable/textbox"
            android:layout_below="@id/etECN"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/textView10"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@id/etECN"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/etECC"
            android:hint=""
            android:textColor="#303030"
            android:background="@drawable/textbox"
            android:layout_below="@id/etECW"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/textView10"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@id/etECW"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/etECE"
            android:hint=""
            android:textColor="#303030"
            android:background="@drawable/textbox"
            android:layout_below="@id/etECC"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/textView10"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@id/etECC"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/etECF"
            android:hint=""
            android:textColor="#303030"
            android:background="@drawable/textbox"
            android:layout_below="@id/etECE"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/textView10"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@id/etECE"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text=":"
            android:id="@+id/textView11"
            android:layout_below="@id/etECF"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/etECF"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@id/textView10"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"/>
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/etDN"
            android:hint=""
            android:textColor="#303030"
            android:background="@drawable/textbox"
            android:layout_below="@id/etECF"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/textView11"
            android:layout_alignTop="@id/textView11"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@id/etECF"/>
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/etDW"
            android:hint=""
            android:textColor="#303030"
            android:background="@drawable/textbox"
            android:layout_below="@id/etDN"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/textView11"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@id/etDN"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/etDF"
            android:hint=""
            android:textColor="#303030"
            android:background="@drawable/textbox"
            android:layout_below="@id/etDW"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/textView11"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@id/etDW"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"

            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/etDE"
            android:hint=""
            android:textColor="#303030"
            android:background="@drawable/textbox"
            android:layout_below="@id/etDF"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/textView11"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@id/etDF"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>


        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:text="Save"
            android:id="@+id/bSave"
            android:background="@drawable/button2"
            android:layout_below="@+id/etDE"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

I looked for this question if it was solved and couldn't find it. If it has been solved then please post that. Otherwise what can I do to prevent the edit text from going behind the other items. Here's the [picture](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B331-HAq34c5VndEbEREaXlIUU0/view?usp=sharing).

Comment: Please provide your complete layout xml code, this is not giving much as input for problem, and you can upload image somewhere else and can share that link over here.

Comment: @Chitrang I uploaded both. Included the entire xml code for this layout.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.oms.track.FinishedSingleItemView" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    >

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <TableLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:padding="5dp" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                    android:text="WORK"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/fini_workname"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="work name"
                    />
            </TableRow>

            <View
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                 />

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:padding="5dp" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                    android:text="ADDRESS"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/fini_address"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="address"
                    />
            </TableRow>

            <View
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                 />

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:padding="5dp" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                    android:text="TIME"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/fini_time"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="14dp"
                    android:hint="09:00 am"
                    />
            </TableRow>

            <View
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                />

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:padding="5dp" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                    android:text="PHONE"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/fini_phone"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="14dp"
                    android:hint="9866421090"
                     />
            </TableRow>

            <View
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                />

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:padding="5dp" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                    android:text="PAYMENT"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/fini_payment"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="14dp"
                    android:hint="0/1"
                    />
            </TableRow>

            <View
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                />


        </TableLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Please check the id's given

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but from what I understand, by putting the individual edit texts into tablerows, that keeps them in their own space, not creating my problem?